# How to get a value from mysql query outside the query statement?

Tags: mysql, node.js

Here is the function see below console.log

```
function quo (value){
    value = connection.query(
       'SELECT role from `roles` where `id` = 1' , 
       function (error, results, fields) {
           if (error) throw error;
           console.log('The role is: ', results[0].role);// result here The role is : admin
          });
    console.log(value);
}
```

The result here is query object Query {domain:null,_events:{error: .. etc} ##

I invoke this like so:

```
quo();
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). **Research, try something, add your code & point your problem.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**tl;dr** everything happens in a callback.

You're tripping up on the asynchronous nature of Javascript.  By the time your `console.log(value);` call runs, the query is not (necessarily) completed. So, there's no way for the result of the query to be available at that time.

Many developers use a pattern like this, with a callback function to handle the next step when the query result arrives.

```
function quo (success){
    value = connection.query(
       'SELECT role from `roles` where `id` = 1' , 
       function (error, results, fields) {
           if (error) throw error;
           console.log('The role is: ', results[0].role);
           success (results[0].role);
       });
}

quo (function (role) {
   console.log(role);
   /* do something useful with the role that came back from the query */
});
```

`Promise` objects make this sort of thing easier to read in node.js. But explaining them is beyond the scope of a Stack Overflow answer anyhow.

Comment: Thank you it is very useful .. my main target is to check the login value of user with database records .. so I can pass this value out of the query itself

Answer (score 0):

```
function quo (success){
    value = connection.query(
       'SELECT role from `roles` where `id` = 1' , 
       function (error, results, fields) {
           if (error) throw error;
           console.log('The role is: ', results[0].role);
           success (results[0].role);
       });
}

quo (function (role) {
   console.log(role);
   /* do something useful with the role that came back from the query */
});
```